# How to speed up UI rendering in Delphi

Tags: user-interface, delphi, tframe, scrollbox

I use a TScrollBox as a list and a TFrame as the Items and I will generate the frames in runtime. The Frame I'm using consists a 3.6KB SVG-Image and some Lables and EditBoxes. As a test, I generated the list with 1000 items in FormShow like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1000 do
    with TFrameCDG.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Name := 'cdgFrame' + IntToStr(i);
      Parent := sbScrollBoxLeft;
    end;
end;
```

Note that I have set the Align property of the frame to alTop and controlled the background color using the events OnExit, OnEnter, OnClick, etc. to make the list look better.

The problem is that the form loads after 38 seconds, resizes in 12 seconds (Maximize), and scrolls very heavily. My cpu is i7-4790, gpu Radeon R7 430, 16GB RAM and I'm using windows 11 and Delphi 10 Seattle.

What's wrong with what I've done?

I deleted the SVG-Image and it took 29 seconds to load. I tried DoubleBuffered and that did not help as I thought.

This list is going to have no more than 50 Items but it is very heavy and slow. How can I accelerate such graphical UI to be smooth like (or near to) what wpf in c# can do?

I created a new project and hier is a minimal example to look at:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Frame2: TFrame};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.


unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 1000 do
    with TFrame2.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Name := 'Framea' + IntToStr(i);
      Parent := ScrollBox1;
    end;
end;

end.




unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Bevel1: TBevel;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FrameEnter(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FrameExit(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFrame2.FrameClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.SetFocus;
end;

procedure TFrame2.FrameEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Color := clBlue;
end;

procedure TFrame2.FrameExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Color := clTeal;
end;

end.




object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 660
  ClientWidth = 1333
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 1333
    Height = 660
    HorzScrollBar.Visible = False
    VertScrollBar.Smooth = True
    VertScrollBar.Tracking = True
    Align = alClient
    TabOrder = 0
  end
end




object Frame2: TFrame2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 451
  Height = 117
  Align = alTop
  Color = clTeal
  Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -19
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  ParentBackground = False
  ParentColor = False
  ParentFont = False
  TabOrder = 0
  OnClick = FrameClick
  OnEnter = FrameEnter
  OnExit = FrameExit
  DesignSize = (
    451
    117)
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 24
    Top = 16
    Width = 55
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Label1'
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWhite
    Font.Height = -19
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object Bevel1: TBevel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 451
    Height = 17
    Align = alTop
    Shape = bsTopLine
    ExplicitLeft = -44
    ExplicitTop = 24
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 131
    Top = 16
    Width = 55
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Label1'
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWhite
    Font.Height = -19
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Left = 238
    Top = 16
    Width = 55
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Label1'
    Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWhite
    Font.Height = -19
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object ProgressBar1: TProgressBar
    Left = 352
    Top = 73
    Width = 77
    Height = 21
    Anchors = [akLeft, akRight, akBottom]
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 24
    Top = 55
    Width = 101
    Height = 38
    BevelInner = bvNone
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    Color = 11184810
    Ctl3D = True
    ParentCtl3D = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Left = 131
    Top = 55
    Width = 101
    Height = 38
    BevelInner = bvNone
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    Color = 11184810
    Ctl3D = True
    ParentCtl3D = False
    TabOrder = 2
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Edit3: TEdit
    Left = 238
    Top = 55
    Width = 101
    Height = 38
    BevelInner = bvNone
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    Color = 11184810
    Ctl3D = True
    ParentCtl3D = False
    TabOrder = 3
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 354
    Top = 36
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Anchors = [akTop, akRight]
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 4
  end
end
```

Comment: How many labels and edit boxes? Is this FMX or VCL?

Comment: It is VCL and there is 6 lables and 2 Edit Boxes. I would add a Button and a ProgressBar as well.

Comment: There is something else going on. VCL should be able to handle this well. Please provide [mcve] especially if there is no image.

Comment: Yes. 8 controls is very few. In general, creating 8 controls should happen immediately. A human should not be able to detect the delay. (Assuming standard VCL controls.)

Comment: I created a new project and edited the post. please take a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your main problem is that you are creating 1001 `TFrame` controls in one go, although you can only show something like max. 10 at any time.

Comment: How to speed up? Don't create more control than what is visible on screen. Store data in data structure, not windowed controls. Then draw what is visible, no more. Have a look at [TVirtualTreeView](https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView) which can probably be configured to produce a list instead of a tree.

Comment: 1001 was just for a test to know how fast is delphi, because it worked not good for 50 TFrames and I decided to test the speed of it with 1001 Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the useful comments, I decided to change my code to obtain a better (not the best) solution. I bring it here because maybe it is useful for others. The logic is that it creates the frames without settin their parents (in memory not on the form) and it is very fast. Then it will set the parent of the could-be-visible frames to Panel1 and also set the right top, on the ScrollChange of the ScrollBar.

By the way, as I mentioned before, I tryed to create so many frames just because I wanted to test the vcl, however the code below works for me good even with 1000 frames:

```
...

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  InvisibleFrames: TArray<TFrame2>;
  NumberOfVisibleFrames: Integer;
  NumberOfInvisibleFrames: Integer;

const
  TrackingPrecision = 20;

...

procedure TForm1.btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  NumberOfInvisibleFrames := 1000;
  SetLength(InvisibleFrames, NumberOfInvisibleFrames * SizeOf(TFrame2));
  for i := 0 to NumberOfInvisibleFrames - 1 do
  begin
    InvisibleFrames[i] := TFrame2.Create(Self);
    InvisibleFrames[i].Name := '';
    InvisibleFrames[i].Label1.Caption := 'Frame: ' + IntToStr(i + 1);
  end;
  Panel1.OnResize := Panel1Resize;
  Panel1Resize(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NumberOfVisibleFrames := Panel1.Height div InvisibleFrames[0].Height + 1;
  ScrollBar1.Min := 0;
  ScrollBar1.Max := Max((NumberOfInvisibleFrames - NumberOfVisibleFrames) * TrackingPrecision, 0);
  ScrollBar1.Enabled := ScrollBar1.Max > 0;
  ScrollBar1.LargeChange := TrackingPrecision * (NumberOfVisibleFrames - 1);
  ScrollBar1.SmallChange := TrackingPrecision;
  ScrollBar1Change(Sender);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  n: Integer;
begin
  SendMessage(Panel1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(False), 0);
  try
    Panel1.Hide;
    for i := 0 to NumberOfInvisibleFrames - 1 do
    begin
      with InvisibleFrames[i] do
      begin
        Parent := nil;
      end;
    end;
    n := ScrollBar1.Position div TrackingPrecision;
    for i := n to n + NumberOfVisibleFrames do
    begin
      if Assigned(InvisibleFrames[i]) then
        with InvisibleFrames[i] do
        begin
          Parent := Panel1;
          Name := '';
          Left := 0;
          Width := Panel1.ClientWidth;
          if ScrollBar1.Enabled then
            Top := Ceil((i - ScrollBar1.Position / TrackingPrecision) * Height +
             (ScrollBar1.Position / ScrollBar1.Max) * (Panel1.Height mod Height - Height))
          else
            Top := i * Height;
        end;
    end;
  finally
    SendMessage(Panel1.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(True), 0);
    Panel1.Show;
  end;
end;
```

It should need some modifications which I will make in my real project, like better error checking, controlling the Items, or releasing the memory and so on.

Or maybe I would make a component from it calling TFrameListBox, if I would have time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `TPanel` as a container instead of `TFrame`.
Call `ScrollBox.DisableAlign` once before adding the panels and `ScrollBox.EnableAlign` after the last panel has been added.
I think you could have some funny behavior if the total panels height reach 32768px. That would require an alternative approach.

Comment: as far as i remeber there is also a additional property thats blocking a repaint. does anyone know? i cant remember currently.

Comment: If Delphi 11 is being used, you can block/unblock the painting by using ScrollBox.LockDrawing/UnlockDrawing.
Or alternatively SendMessage(ScrollBox.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, Ord(False), 0) and SendMessage(WindowHandle, WM_SETREDRAW, Ord(True), 0)